# Username and password encryption

Tags: security, drupal-7

Drupal send the login credentials(username and password) in plain text even on HTTPs also.
Enters the username password. Before this firebug is open. Navigate to Net section and check post variables after submitting login form. I can see my username and password in plain text form.

I have tested this on drupal.org also. Drupal.org is also sending the password in clear text.

Can it be encrypted? Is there any way to encrypt the password before sending the form data to validator function.

Comment: In most circumstances the HTTPS will be sufficient protection from somebody seeing the password on the wire as the requests themselves will be encrypted between browser and server (barring any man in the middle attacks, corporate proxies or malware).

You could encrypt the password client side in JavaScript - perhaps using the public key of the certificate that is bound to the HTTPS port, then customize drupal to decrypt the password before executing the authentication... but technically that would be vunerable to the same attacks as HTTPS.

Comment: In drupal it is not working.

Comment: Firebug is just displaying the data because it monitored it before the connection is encrypted.

If you were to use Wireshark, or Fiddler (without enabling the HTTPS proxy) the password should indeed be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this module: Encrypt Submissions  https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt_submissions

Comment: i have installed this module but its reloaded the login form after ?q=encrypt-submissions/generate-keypair&esrnd=VfTP0vTuRepeKsQUnOE6 generated key pair but not redirected to user's dashboard